# How to perform Xpath looping on a series of attributes?

Tags: xml, loops, xpath, tokenize

I am working on extracting parts of a XML file.
And I need to get the three third values of Data (which are `1.25`, `1.9` and `2.92`, respectively).

The XML file code is as follows:

```
<logData>
<data>499,498.99,1.25,0,1.45,3.67,11.02,187.66,0.29,116.24,0.01,0.05,0.01,0,886.03,1089.99,1.11,14.67,0.29,1.12,1.11</data>
<data>500.01,500,1.9,0.01,1.42,9.94,11.32,185.7,0.29,116.24,0.01,0.01,0.01,0,795.19,973.48,1.11,14.67,0.29,0.95,1.11</data> 
<data>501.03,501.02,2.92,0.02,1.41,20.46,11.62,184.23,0.29,120,0.01,0.01,0.01,0,796.68,956.25,1.11,14.67,0.29,0.83,1.11</data>
   </logData>
```

`(tokenize(//logData/data,','))[3]` returns a wrong message"

> “Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item
>   is not allowed as the first argument of tokenize().”

Since Xpath loops automatically, there should be a syntax that allows selecting the first set of data to apply tokenize, then move to the next set, and so one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `tokenize()` accept input as string and returns string value.
If you want to fetch values you probably have to pass `xpath` with indexes.

```
tokenize(//logData/data[1],',')[3] #returns 1.25

tokenize(//logData/data[2],',')[3] #returns 1.9

tokenize(//logData/data[last()],',')[3] #returns 2.92
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer KunduK. However, in order to clarify my question, i would say that I am looking for a syntax that returns all the three third values in one time: 1.25, 1.9 & 2.92 ! Is there any way to get it ?

Comment: @Jun : I don't think so. you have to use loop to pass the indexes.As i mentioned if you see the `tokenize()` function it accepts string as input not the array.

Comment: Therefore, any idea how I can loop this ?! ^^

Comment: @Jun - It's possible to loop thru this using any python library which supports the `tokenize()` method. I can post an example, if you're interested.

Comment: @KunduK : is there no alternative option to loop on ?

Comment: which language are you trying?

Comment: @KunduK - The language i'm trying is Java